# How to parse JSON into UITableview

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, rest, swift2

i have to download and parse a JSON file into a UITableView in Swift 2.0

I don't really want to use 3rd party frameworks like SwiftyJSON.

I got it working with one swift file which looked a little something like that:

```
[
  {
   "id": "1",
   "title": "Test Shindig",
   "dateOfEvent": "2015-12-25 00:00:00",
   "totalGuests": 6
  }
]
```

so I have an array of dictionaries.

The JSON I am struggling with is this one:

```
{
  "guests": [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "firstName": "Burp",
     "lastName": "Derp",
    },
   ],
  "total": 6,
  "totalCheckedIn": 1
}
```

So if I'm not mistaken thats an Dictionary containing an array and 2 Integers

Whatever I try, I can't get anything back from my API call.

There is also no way for me to change the JSONs in anyway.

I hope anybody can help me!

Cheers, Niklas

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any 3rd party framework, you could do the parsing manually. The best practice would suggest creating a struct for a Guest object and a struct for the entire response (GuestList).

```
struct GuestList {
  var guests: [Guest]
  var total: Int
  var totalCheckedIn: Int

  init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
    total = data["total"] as! Int
    totalCheckedIn = data["totalCheckedIn"] as! Int
    let list = data["guests"] as! [AnyObject]
    guests = [Guest]()

    for guest: [String: AnyObject] in list {
      guests.append(Guest(data: guest))
    }
  }
}


struct Guest {
  var id: Int
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String

  init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
    id = data["id"] as! Int
    firstName = data["firstName"] as! String
    lastName = data["lastName"] as! String
  }
}
```

This is a quick implementation with a lot of `!`, so you should be careful about that. This code is also not tested, but it should give you a pretty good idea as to how to parse your JSON response.